# Porting ios to android: http post

Tags: android, ios, http-post, porting

Trying to post image with additional data.

IOS code:

```
NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
[params setValue:userID forKey:@"userid"];
[params setValue:sessionID forKey:@"sessionid"];

CWNetworkOperation *operation = [self operationWithURL:url httpMethod:@"POST" params:params];
NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.8f);
[operation setData:imageData forKey:@"photo" mimeType:@"image/jpeg" fileName:@"image.jpg"];
```

Can add userid and sessionid as org.apache.http.NameValuePair

to org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost, but adding "photo" key with encoded to base64 string image byte array value doesn't give positive result.

Sniffer screen:

[image]

How to make the same in java?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran into the same problem when porting my app to android. I ended up using the apache networking libraries as described in this article. This has all the info needed for a multi-form POST. I can't remember where I download the the JAR files off apache's website but I ran across this:

http://blog.tacticalnuclearstrike.com/2010/01/using-multipartentity-in-android-applications/

Should give the general idea on what to do.

Comment: Thanks! Will check out this a little later and will give you my feedback.
But at first look it seems the right solution.